# Delete line in TSTringlist

Tags: delphi

Hello i am writing some values to a stringlist. And would like to delete a value from the string list.

Currently I write to the string list like this.

```
   FGamePlay.Locations.strings[0] := ('NumberOfLocations='+inttostr(NOL+1));   //add one to total
   FGameplay.Locations.Add(inttostr(Position.x)+inttostr(Position.Y)+'=pos');  //add the location to list
```

This will return me a list like so

```
INDEX    VALUE
[0]       NumberOfLocations=4
[1]       23=pos
[2]       34=pos
[3]       24=pos
[4]       52=pos
```

Now i try to delete it like this

```
FGamePlay.Locations.Delete(FGamePlay.Locations.IndexOf(inttostr(ePosition.x)+inttostr(ePosition.Y)));
```

were ePosition.x + ePosition.Y will equal 23, 34,24,or 52.  Thus it should delete the that line but instead when i add this delete line i get index out of bounds -1. I did stop the code just before this line and looked at Locations() and it had all these numbers in there. Also looked at epostion and the X,Y values were 34, thus correct too. Any idea?
thanks
Glen

Comment: You are missing the `+'=pos'` in the delete sentence.

Comment: Ever thought of using a more appropriate data structure that is made for the data you need to hold?

Comment: Like ?  I thought this structure works out good? Was the best way to keep locations and items on the map? But I am sure. There is always a better way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you uses the [`IndexOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf) function you must pass the exact string to find, in this case since you are adding the strings in this way

```
FGameplay.Locations.Add(inttostr(Position.x)+inttostr(Position.Y)+'=pos');
```

You must add the `=pos` to the string to search, something like

```
LIndex:=FGamePlay.Locations.IndexOf(inttostr(ePosition.x)+inttostr(ePosition.Y)+'=pos');
If LIndex>=0 then
 FGamePlay.Locations.Delete(LIndex);
```

Comment: This is still terrible code.  +1 for helping the OP out, but for the love of Mike, please, Glen, don't stringly-type everything you do.

Comment: Or use IndexOfName() ... that is arguably polishing the pig unless the "=pos" part is, or could become, potentially variable (i.e. not guaranteed to be "=pos" for every item) in which case it is not polishing the pig but a necessary change.  :)

Answer (score 1):

As RRUZ says, the string you are looking for to delete is missing the "=pos" suffix.

In order to debug this more effectively, you should break up the code a bit more. If you had this equivalent code:

```
str := inttostr(ePosition.x)+inttostr(ePosition.Y);
pos := FGamePlay.Locations.IndexOf(str);
FGamePlay.Locations.Delete(pos);
```

You would get an error on the `pos :=` line, which would allow to to see the source of the error much more easily.

You could also consider making a function like:

```
function MakePosString(Position : Point);
begin
   Result := inttostr(ePosition.x)+inttostr(ePosition.Y)+'=pos';
end;
```

Then you can call that function instead of reimplementing that code and you are guaranteed that your strings will be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with everything everyone else has said about considering using a better data structure for the job at hand, I think for the sake of anyone with a similar problem in the future it is worth mentioning something that nobody else yet identified.

Your expression:

```
IntToStr(ePosition.x) + IntToStr(ePosition.y)
```

identifies the NAME of an entry in your string list, when considered as a name/value list.  That is, a TStringList where each item is of the form "name=value".   Whilst one way to fix your code is to append the rest of the string ('=pos') this of course only works when the "value" part of every named value is always "pos".

If there is the possibility that the "pos" value could be different or unknown for a given named value, then you can still find it by looking up the index of the item using just the name part:

```
  itemName  := IntToStr(ePosition.x) + IntToStr(ePosition.y);
  itemIndex := fGamePlay.Locations.IndexOfName(itemName);
  if itemIndex > -1 then
    fGamePlay.Locations.Delete(IndexOfName(itemName));
```

Comment: The pos does change but for this part of the code when it deletes it will always delete the = pos part